# How do I return results that begin with a or A?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL Select statement that will return all results that begin with an 'a' or an 'A'.  (In other words, not case sensitive.)  The way I think I should write this is as follows:

SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR 'A%';

No results are returned. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The answer from @MikeB is best. Your problem is in the `WHERE` statement. What you actually want is `WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR name LIKE 'A%';` Your statement will return any records where name starts with "a" and then the other statement doesn't do anything.

Comment: What database server are you using?  This doesn't run in SQL Server, with error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I like MikeB's answer, you would get better performance by using an OR:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR name like 'A%'
```

This is because you wouldn't apply an `upper` on every `name`, which can't use the index.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I had tried "name LIKE 'a%' OR LIKE 'A%'", but hadn't thought of repeating "LIKE name" again after the OR.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE upper(name) LIKE 'A%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  You had this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR 'A%'
```

add the words "name like"  to get this"

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR name like 'A%'
```